# Different behavior from sed when executed in place

Tags: linux, sed

Let's assume I have `fruit.txt` with the following contents:

```
apple
banana
cantaloupe
donut peach
elderberries
```

I want to cut the list off before cantaloupe, so I run

```
$ sed -ne '/cantaloupe/q;p' fruit.txt 
apple
banana
```

Perfect. Now I want to modify my fruit list in place:

```
$ sed -ine '/cantaloupe/q;p' fruit.txt
$ cat fruit.txt
apple
apple
banana
banana
cantaloupe
```

But wait, now it seems `-n` didn't suppress the output anymore? Can anybody explain what's going on here and how to make it do what I want? I realize I can easily use a temp file, but I'd like to understand why `sed` behaves this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing your `sed` interpreted `ne` as the backup argument for the `-i` option. Try specifying each option separately, without clustering.

(If this is correct, you should find the original file in `fruit.txtne` in the current directory.)

Comment: Aha, you are exactly right.  I even had a fruit.txtne without realizing it ;). Thanks!